# Is a Gorgon's Petrifying Breath a poison attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The Gorgon has an action for "Petrifying Breath" that causes petrification if recipient fails two con saves.

My question is whether or not this weapon is a "poison" so that the Paladin Lay On Hands could end the petrification or if only Greater Restoration or Wish can do it.

The Monster Manual states:

> The gorgon exhales petrifying gas  in  a 30-foot cone.  Each  creature in that area
>   must succeed on a  DC  13  Constitution saving throw.  On  a
>   failed save, a target begins to turn to stone and  is  restrained.
>   The restrained target must repeat the saving throw at the end
>   of  its next turn. On a success, the  effect ends on the target.
>   On a failure, the target  is  petrified until freed  by  the  greater
>   restoration  spell or other magic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is not a poison attack. Nowhere in the power description is the word poison mentioned.

True, it does act a bit like some other poison effects, but without the mention of the keyword "poison" it's hard to see how this could be interpreted as a poison that would be curable by Lay on Hands.

Comment: I also agree on this interpretation, because it seems like something that Lay on Hands shouldn't fix, given that its such a low level class feature. Leaving out poison wording seems like RAI.

Comment: You could also mention that it is not a disease either. Especially since Lay on Hands would also cure a disease.

Comment: I agree, the cleric lesser restoration (level 2) can end the effect of poison, but it takes cleric greater restoration (level 5) to undo PETRIFIED.